# How to create multiple orbital paths around a sphere dynamically in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a atom simulator kind of project. So what I am currently doing is from the periodic table when user clicks on any of the element, I will spawn a sphere gameobject (i.e atom) for that element. Now as atoms have electrons with different shell configuration around them. I am trying to simulate that effect. I am able to create a single orbital path around the sphere(atom) and spawned an electron sphere which rotates around the atom nicely.

**Here is what it looks like**

[image]

I am doing this using the following code.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.RotateAround(rotateAround.position, Vector3.forward, rotationSpeed);
}
```

Now I am trying to have multiple orbital path around atom(like n shell, p shell etc). I tried adding some offset to the transform that is passed in the rotate around method, but then the path was not completely circular.

So how can I create something like that.

Comment: Have you tried changing `Vector3.forward` to a random `new Vector3(x, y, z)`?

Comment: @CùĐứcHiếu But according to the definition, it just the axis around which it will rotate. I want to have it a different radius orbit.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the radius is the distance from electron to proton(s) and you can manipulate that distance (increase or decrease), can't you? And that it will create different radius orbits. The second parameter when uses properly can make the 2 planes containing 2 orbits perpendicular to each other or something like that.

Comment: That's what I want to know how to manipulate radius properly. I tried by changing the rotateAround position by adding some offset to it in y and x axis but the path was not proper.

Comment: You place the electron in its proper shell and than use RotateAround, the radius will be unchanging. If you want to change its radius, place it a bit further away from atom and than use RotateAround.

Comment: @ArmanPapikyan question is about creating shells with different radius

Comment: Do you mean some visual representation or what? I dont really understand the problem.

Comment: The one rotating around currently is by using the code that I have written in the update method. In that I just pass the transform of the sphere around which I wanted to rotate it. But now I want to have path with different radius around the spheres. I don't want any visual representation for path. I just want electrons to rotate around a certain path of different radius

Comment: Maybe this should help: First you create an electron at the position of the proton. Second, you move it to the left `p` units by using `transform.postion += p * Vector3.left`. It should be done in the `Start()` method. Then your `Update()` method will handle the rotaion.

Comment: I can't do this in start as atoms are spawned via prefab when clicked by the user. I will try the next part.

Comment: They are rotating around an object who's transform you passed by maintaining the same distance they had at the start. If you are attaching this script to all of them, than just attach it to a new electron gameObject, but make sure to place it a little farther away before attaching it, or at start.
You can always write a sin/cos function to make it rotate in any spherical trajectory nicely by passing the radius, direction and speed, but for your case that is not needed.

Comment: Oh yes, then you can do it when you spawn your electron. When spawning electron, you have to set its position. That is where you put the code.

Comment: Of course you can do that at start. Have that rotation script attached as a component in the prefab, when new electrong gameObject is spawned it's start gets called, you change its position once (setting it to a proper orbit) and it keeps rotating in update maintaining that radius.

Comment: Let me try this. I will let you know if this works or not.

Comment: "I can't do this in start as atoms are spawned via prefab when clicked by the user." I don't know what you mean tbh, distance of orbit is mag(nucleus - electron), so just create a min->max radius range, and multiply a randomized; normalized vector by it, add the new vector to the position of the nucleus, and wallah.

Comment: @CùĐứcHiếu thanks man! Your suggestion worked perfectly.

Comment: Wow, I didn't though it was that simple :D. I will make it an answer so that it is easier to look up for anyone coming here later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to spawn electrons somewhere in your code.
Locate that piece of code and do the following:

1. Set the electron's position to proton's position.
2. Shift it to the left `p` units by using this code: `transform.position += p * Vector3.left`.
3. Your `Update()` method will handle the rotation. You can further refine it by changing `Vector3.forward` to a random `new Vector3(x, y, z)` so that the plane containing the orbit will rotate as well which will create a more realistic effect.